# Using the default DLQ for a queue in Azure Service Bus using MassTransit

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit, azure-servicebus-queues

MassTransit uses a new queue (`_error`) to put failed messages in. I read that this behavior can be changed for subscriptions (https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#subscription-endpoint-changes), but can this also be applied to receive endpoints (queues)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can customize the receive endpoint to use the dead-letter queue:

```csharp
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue-name", e =>
{
    e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueDeadLetterTransport();
    e.ConfigureDeadLetterQueueErrorTransport();

    e.ConfigureConsumer<T>(context);
});
```

The same approach can be used anywhere a receive endpoint is being configured.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, hadn't found that

Comment: A lot of these little things aren't documented, happy to help out.